# Update SQL inplace

Tags: sql

I want to correct some columns with wrong length in character.

Where is my fault in this syntax?

```
UPDATE tbl 
SET column = (SELECT (left(string, 3) + 
                      left(right(string, 8), 6) + 
                      right(string, 1)) 
              FROM tbl  
              WHERE LEN(string) <> 10)
```

Comment: Please tag dbms. Some non-ANSI SQL there...

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery will not find the same row you're updating, so the logic will not be as you expect.

The good news is, you don't need a subquery at all since you're only operating on a single row at a time.

```
UPDATE tbl 
 SET column = LEFT(column, 3) + LEFT(RIGHT(column, 8), 6) + RIGHT(column, 1)
WHERE LEN(column) <> 10
```

Comment: There's an extra closing round bracket at the end of the query